# Issue creating a Checkpoint Host with Ansible

Tags: ansible, checkpoint

I am trying to create a Checkpoint host on my SMS using Ansible but i am encountering some issues.

Below are some information that might be helpful.

Playbook:

```
---
- name: Checkpoint Hosts Management
  hosts: firewalls_checkpoint
  tasks:
    - name: Add a new Host
      check_point.mgmt.cp_mgmt_host:
        ip_address: 192.0.2.1
        name: New Host 1
        state: present
        auto_publish_session: yes
```

Inventory

```
#This is a group of remote servers for Checkpoint SMS
[firewalls_checkpoint]
ckp_sms

#These are global variables for the group firewalls
[firewalls_checkpoint:vars]
ansible_httpapi_use_ssl=True
ansible_httpapi_validate_certs=False
ansible_user=admin
ansible_password=*****
ansible_ssh_pass=*****
ansible_network_os=check_point.mgmt.checkpoint
ansible_ssh_transfer_method=scp
```

ansible.cfg

```
[defaults]
host_key_checking = False

[ssh_connection]
scp_if_ssh=True
timeout = 100
```

However, when i run my playbook with command ansible-playbook /etc/ansible/playbooks/checkpoint/network_create.yml, i get the following error:

```
fatal: [ckp_sms]: FAILED! => {
    "msg": "failed to transfer file to /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-local-71858l7zedua/tmpj8i_7uay CLINFR0711  Command insecure/AnsiballZ_setup.py:\n\nCLINFR0329  Invalid command:'scp -t 'CLINFR0711  Command insecure/AnsiballZ_setup.py''.\n"
}
```

If i ssh directly on a terminal to the SMS, it works fine.

I get the same error message when i try to ping the sms using ansible -m ping

The link for the Checkmate post is here https://community.checkpoint.com/t5/Ansible/Issue-creating-a-host-with-Ansible/m-p/100715#M388 (For Checkpoint users)

Can someone please help me out.

Comment: Try to execute your playbook with `-vvvv` option, it will show the commands ansible is trying to execute and you may find more info on what's not working.